# Sideloaded app requires package Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00 on my build server

Tags: windows-store-apps, sideloading

In trying to run integration tests on my windows store app but the sideloading of my test appx file fails with error (0x80073CF3):

```
Windows cannot install package (my package GUID) because this package depends on another package that could not be found. This package requir
es minimum version 12.0.21005.1 of framework Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00 published by any publisher to install. Provide the framework along with this package..
```

The same procedure works fine on my dev machine (from powershell).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/08/01/c-runtime-for-sideloaded-windows-8-1-apps/) states:

> ...In order to facilitate this scenario for sideloaded apps, we have made
>   the framework packages available [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/F/0/5F0F8404-9329-44A9-8176-ED6F7F746F25/VCLibs_Redist_Packages.zip).

After [downloading](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/F/0/5F0F8404-9329-44A9-8176-ED6F7F746F25/VCLibs_Redist_Packages.zip), and extracting the relevant architecture appx file, I installed it via powershell:

```
 Add-AppxPackage "C:\temp\Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00_12.0.21005.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe.appx"
```